# How do i interpolate '%' into css value in stylus?

Tags: stylus

so i'm trying to interpolate '%' into a css value in a for loop in stylus

here's the code

```
for i in (1..100)
   .c-h{i}
     height {i}%
```

but it isn't working

I've been scratching my head for hours, please any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!
All i had to do was substitute `{}` for `()` in the value

```
for i in (1..100)
 .c-h{i}
    height (i)%
```